# Watson Conversation API response inconsistent with workspace response on Watson web console

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I built a conversations dialog model that works perfectly when tested on the www.ibmwatsonconversation.com workspace.

However, when I use the API calling the same workspace on my web app, the response given through the API not the same.

Below is the flow:

Intent 1

Intent 2 -> Entity 1

Intent 3

Intended behavior :

1.Ask question with intent 2, get reply from intent 2 node.

2.Enter entity 1, get reply from entity 1 node.

Actual behaviour (only from API):

1. Ask question with intent 2, get reply from intent 2 node.
2. Enter entity 1, get reply from intent 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely cause for this is that you are not passing back the context object at every call. Conversation is stateless, so without the context object it can't determine where you are, and will default to root.

Your first call will create the context object, and you can keep passing that back.

If this isn't is the issue, you need to supply a demo of the issue with dummy data, or a screenshot of your dialog flow (related part only).

Comment: Thanks for the help! I did not update the context which caused it to go back to the root node everytime