# Watson conversation output always same message even intent and input has changed (curl API with php)

Tags: php, curl, watson-conversation

I am trying to use the Watson conversation API for question and answer.. I am trying to call API for a particular conversation but every time it return the same output and the first level output. Can anybody help me on this? i am using php and curl to call

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) ! Please read  [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) !

Comment: Hi, have you tried testing the conversation in the Watson Conversation tool?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Watson Conversation API response inconsistent with workspace response on Watson web console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39586350/watson-conversation-api-response-inconsistent-with-workspace-response-on-watson)

Comment: yes this question already asked but can't find the code . can you give code of passing back the context object at every call from php

Comment: @RiyaMRoy yes it works fine in bluemix .here is the link http://conversation-simple.mybluemix.net/

Comment: https://github.com/keithweaver/ibm-watson-php-sdk It might be out of date though.